# HTML & CSS question: Element between two absolute-positioned elements needs to resize correctly

Tags: html, css, resize

```
#header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    height: 24px;
}
#body
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    bottom: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 17.2%;
    min-height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

My problem is that when I compress the browser window, the middle element (the 'body') starts to slip into the footer's area (when 20% from the bottom becomes larger than the minimum height of the footer).  The footer can be larger in height than its minimum, but it cannot be smaller.

Any good way to do this without Javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When an element is positioned absolutely it is removed from the flow of the document and has no knowledge of any other elements.

I have not seen a sticky-footer solution that will work with a variable height footer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples of [headers](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-top-frame-layout/) and [footers](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-bottom-frame-layout/) on Dynamic Drive. These are pure CSS layout examples.

You should be able to achieve the same effect with a combination of these two.

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work, but my problem is that I want my footer to be AT LEAST 80px, but otherwise whatever 17.2% of the browser window currently is if larger.  In other words, I need it to grow dynamically.